# WPF - Sample App, Step by Step

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF development. Is anyone aware of a site or resource that builds a somewhat simple WPF application step by step, with ample explanation and/or documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has a series of blog posts in which he builds a WPF application called "BabySmash", sounds like it might be along the lines of what you're looking for. The first post is [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingBabySmashAWPFExperiment.aspx), and all of the posts can be found under the [BabySmash category](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=BabySmash) on his site.

Comment: One of the nice things about BabySmash is the way Hanselman "thinks out loud" as he struggles to adjust to the *idioms and patterns* of WPF.  He isn't content to just show the mechanics of building an app, he tries to show how he has to change the very way he designs the app.  A very important adjustment!

Answer (score 1):

Months before I was also searching for stuffs like what you asked. Here I can provide you the best link for building a WPF application step by step with total documentation. This project demonstrates where to use which controls at what extend. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tims/archive/2007/06/13/wpf-hands-on-lab-build-an-outlook-2007-ui-clone.aspx

It is a hands-on lab that demonstrates the steps to create a user interface for business applications using WPF and Expression Blend.

Have a nice day.